# Secure URL is return ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Why Secure URL is return ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with WordPress?

- if i am using single index.php then https is working.
- if i add wordpress project at same directory with WP_HOME = https then it return `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.
- if i add wordpress project at same directory with WP_HOME = http then it is working but console return `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS using httpd`, and it is not display properly.

htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: add .htaccess file for wordpress folder.

Comment: Added @Vaibhavi Sojitra

Answer (score 0):

Add `.htaccess` file for wordpress sub directory folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: try to change by this code. and replace `my_subdir` with you wordpress project folder name. @SohilSardhara

Comment: The requested URL /my_subdir/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @SohilSardhara replace with you project folder.

Comment: Yes, i updated it with my project folder name, then it return The requested URL / my project folder /index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: When `define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com')` then it return ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and when `define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com')` then working without css and console display like `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS using httpd`

Comment: @SohilSardhara did you include any third party url with https:// in your header or fotter.??

Comment: Remove `define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com')` from config file. and add `https://example.com` into your database wp_options file directly. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error because of from many file same url redirection there.

Comment: Same error with `https` url it return `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` and with `http` working without css and console display like `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS using httpd`